# iPhone Developer Code Signing Identity not showing up for iOS 7

Tags: xcode5, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

Not too long ago I upgraded to XCode 5. My iOS Development certificate also expired, so i re-downloaded it and installed in keychain.

Now in XCode the certificate DOES show up under "Code Signing Identity" in the "Debug" section, but does NOT show up under "Any iOS SDK".

[image]

Any idea what's wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved!

The trick here, I think, is that Provisioning Profiles contain a list of developer Certificates that are allowed by that profile. If a certificate expires, I believe the profile must be re-created, re-downloaded, and re-installed.

I went to "Provisioning Profiles > All" in [Apple's Developer Connect website](https://developer.apple.com/account/overview.action), chose the development profile that had formerly contained my expired Certificate, chose Select All for all developers and devices, and re-generated and re-downloaded the certificate (after having deleted the previous one from the iPad using XCode's Organizer). Now it works!